# Scheduling procedures in mongoDB in Windows

Tags: mongodb, procedures

How can I create a `mongodb procedure` that can be scheduled to run once every day, at a fix time, say sharp at midnight GMT?

This [google group link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/OfKzKuSm6wQ) says you cannot schedule a task in mongoDB, they have a [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-124) for this, but you can use `Window Task Scheduler` which is described in [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). Is this the only way to achieve it? Is this a good way to do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845707/backend-stored-procedure-schedulers-in-mongodb-database This also says use a `scripting language` to achieve it. So, I think I will need to use script to schedule the task in windows. Am i correct?

Comment: [As written in a different answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178128/why-mongodb-performance-better-on-linux-than-on-windows/24187943#24187943), running MongoDB on Windows is a bad idea for various reasons. Under Linux, you could use `crond` to run a `.js` file easily. If your requirement is to run MongoDB and have a reliable scheduler, the right tool for the job is Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the comment by @Markus,

[As written in a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24178128/why-mongodb-performance-better-on-linux-than-on-windows/24187943#24187943), running MongoDB on Windows is a bad idea for various reasons. Under Linux, you could use crond to run a .js file easily. If your requirement is to run MongoDB and have a reliable scheduler, the right tool for the job is Linux.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16845707/backend-stored-procedure-schedulers-in-mongodb-database) also mentions the way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is done on Windows the same way you do on Linux.

ONE: Make a script in JavaScript to manage the task. This can be done in other languages if you prefer. This is a JavaScript script to rotate logs.

```
use admin
db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } )
```

TWO: Create a task in Task Scheduler to run the script. This can be done with the GUI, the API, or in XML. I usually set it up in the GUI and export the XML to allow parameterization of the database server, password, port, and user.

THREE: Include the execution of the script in the task

```
$MONGO_HOME/Mongo localhost:27017 -u myMongoServiceAccount -p somepassword LogRotate.js
```

The same concept can be applied to index management, gathering database stats, or managing stale locks.