# Executing a script when Mongoose timer expires

Tags: node.js, mongoose, timer

I have a model and I want to set a timer such that after an instance of the model is created, a `timer` is counting down for 1 hour. When `timer` expires, I want to be able to execute a script. Any ideas?

```
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var mySchema = new Schema({
    timer: {
        type: Date,
        expires: '1h'
    }
});
```

**Edit:**

Andy here. I'm the creator of the bounty and am not the original poster. I opened this bounty because I haven't figured out a way to confidently track an expiring document. I'm using [mongoose-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cron) to create a job for each user created match. If there are no issues with the server (restarts/crashes/etc.) the cron job expires on time (24 hours) and I set an expired property to `false` for the associated document.

The problem is when the server has some sort of interruption. In that case, the cron job is destroyed or—at least—disassociated with the closure I created (feeding in the correct document). Because of this, I don't think cron jobs are the answer and am hoping to find an approach I can trust in production environments.

Comment: Is `timer` needs to be maintain between node.js process restart?

Answer (score 0):

It seems more a logic work than a *Mongoose Schema* job.
Why do not execute a script on the server when an instance is created?

Maybe, no guaranty, you can do it your way with [mongoose-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-cron) npm module. You could also have a look at [mongoose-function](https://github.com/mongoosejs/mongoose-function) who seems interesting too.

Another possibility you can try to store function (a bit like SQL stored procedure), but again this is apparently not encouraged as it is said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16845836/5156280) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider this following solution.

A separate `notifications` project to handle all the `timer` related functionality.

1. As soon as instance of `Model` is created register a `cron` event with data and store it in database.
2. `notifications` module check for upcoming `cron` event in database and execute as soon as timer expire with data.

As maintaining `timer` is independent from model creation so restart server can be maintain easily.

I have a [notifications](https://github.com/maninder-singh/notifications/) github project that can register cron event and store it in database and execute it after completion.

In `notifications` i am sending email after cron completion you can handle as per your requirement.

Change `sendNotification` method in file `notifications/app/message.js`

```
messages.sendNotification = (data) => {
    if(data.length === 0){
        logger.info(`No notifications to send on ${moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")}`);
        return;
    }
    data.forEach(function (row) {
        mailer.send({
            subject:"Notifications Message",
            to:row.recipient_email,
            text:row.data
        },updateNotificationStatus(row));
    });
};
```

Configure `notifications` to fetch latest cron events from database as per your need.

```
Source file - /notifications/config/config.js

config.CRON_JOB_RULE = "0 11 * * *"; // daily at 11 am
```

For cron register you have to make POST request `/notifications` with json data.

Sample POST request

```
var data = {
          "email":"",
          "date":"",
          "message":""
      };

$.ajax({
            url:"/notifications",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType:"json",
            data:JSON.stringify(data)
        });
```

Comment: Interesting approach for scalability , but you said this "As maintaining timer is independent from model creation so restart server can be maintain easily". For this to be true the DB code for moving the document must be in timer project yes?

Comment: @LumbusterTick not necessarily you can save only the document id and when notification is trigger you got the data ( any json structure ) and do your computation